# Find files in directory modified at various times

Tags: bash, find, unix-timestamp, gnu-findutils

Bash newbie here. The task is to find all files in a (rather large) directory whose modification date falls between various pairs of times. These times are specified as Unix timestamps in a CSV file:

```
1483743420,1483747020
1484348640,1484352240
1484953920,1484957520
1485559200,1485562800
1486164480,1486168080
1486769820,1486773420
```

My early thought was to use `find` and `awk`:

```
find "$PROJECT_DIR" -type f \
-newermt "$(awk -F "","" '{print $1}' "$DATE_CSV")" -not \
-newermt "$(awk -F "","" '{print $2}' "$DATE_CSV")"
```

`find` doesn't seem to recognize this date format. More pressingly, this code only sends the first date to `find`, and the rest are printed:

```
$ bash datefind.sh
find: Can't parse date/time: 1483743420
1484348640
1484953920
1485559200
1486164480
1486769820
```

Is there a way to do this with a single find command? Or should I be trying something else?

Comment: Surely you would want *newer* than one date and *older* than another in order to make a range?

Comment: Can you please add an example of csv file and example of output file

Comment: @MarkSetchell This was the point of the ! operator. Code has been updated for clarity.

Comment: @shaikisiegal Sample input and output have been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU find:

```
PROJECT_DIR="/tmp"
DATE_CSV="file"
find "$PROJECT_DIR" \( -type f \) -a \( $(awk -F ',' 'NR==1 { print "-newermt @" $1 " -not -newermt @" $2 }; NR!=1 { print "-o -newermt @" $1 " -not -newermt @" $2 }' "$DATE_CSV") \)
```

From `man find`:

> `-newermt`: Time specifications are interpreted as for the argument to the -d option of GNU date.
>
> `-o`: logical OR
>
> `-a`: logical AND

---

What awk does:

```
DATE_CSV="file"
awk -F ',' 'NR==1 { print "-newermt @" $1 " -not -newermt @" $2 }; NR!=1 { print "-o -newermt @" $1 " -not -newermt @" $2 }' "$DATE_CSV"
```

Output:

```
-newermt @1483743420 -not -newermt @1483747020
-o -newermt @1484348640 -not -newermt @1484352240
-o -newermt @1484953920 -not -newermt @1484957520
-o -newermt @1485559200 -not -newermt @1485562800
-o -newermt @1486164480 -not -newermt @1486168080
-o -newermt @1486769820 -not -newermt @1486773420
```